# Select drop down value not getting received in an email while other fields are, using JS and php in an email form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I am using the following html, JS and php to send an email form. All values are being received in the mail except select option drop down value. I want people and roomtype values to be mailed along with other data.

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="bookingForm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="message-name" id="name" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Your Name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" name="message-email" id="email" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Your Email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Phone</label>
                                        <input type="number" name="message-phone" id="phone" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Your Phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Arrival Date</label>
                                        <input type="date" name="message-arrival" id="arrival" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Arrival Date *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter arrival date." value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Departure Date</label>
                                        <input type="date" name="message-departure" id="departure" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Departure Date *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter arrival date." value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>No. of People</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="people" name="people" required data-validation-required-message="Please select number of people.">
                                          <option value="" disabled selected>Select no.s of people *</option>
                                          <option value="1">1</option>
                                          <option value="2">2</option>
                                          <option value="3">3</option>
                                          <option value="4">4</option>
                                          <option value="5">5</option>
                                          <option value="6">6</option>
                                          <option value="7">7</option>
                                          <option value="8">8</option>
                                          <option value="9">9</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Room/ Suite Type</label> 
                                        <select class="form-control" name="roomtype" id="roomtype"  required data-validation-required-message="Please select type of room/ suite.">
                                              <option value="" disabled selected>Select Room/Suite *</option>
                                             <option value="1"> Family Suite-I </option>
                                             <option value="2"> Family Suite-II </option>
                                             <option value="3"> Double Bed Room  </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <br/><label>Comments</label>
                                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control mb-30" placeholder="Your Message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
                                <div id="success"></div><!--Required for Mail Sent-->
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn roberto-btn mt-15">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

This is the Java script.

```
// Booking Form Scripts
$(function() {
$("#bookingForm input,#bookingForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
preventSubmit: true,
submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
// additional error messages or events
},
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
// get values from FORM
var name = $("input#name").val();
var email = $("input#email").val();
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
var arrival = $("input#arrival").val();
var departure = $("input#departure").val();
var people = $("input#people").val();
var roomtype = $("input#roomtype").val();
var message = $("textarea#message").val();
var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
// Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
}
$.ajax({
url: "././mail/bookmail/mail/book.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
name: name,
email: email,
phone: phone,
arrival: arrival,
departure: departure,
people: people,
roomtype: roomtype,
message: message
},
cache: false,
success: function() {
// Success message
$('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
$('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
.append("</button>");
$('#success > .alert-success')
.append("<strong>Your message has been sent. Will Contact you Shortly. </strong>");
$('#success > .alert-success')
.append('</div>');

//clear all fields
$('#bookingForm').trigger("reset");
},
error: function() {
// Fail message
$('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
$('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
.append("</button>");
$('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
$('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
//clear all fields
$('#bookingForm').trigger("reset");
},
});
},
filter: function() {
return $(this).is(":visible");
},
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).tab("show");
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
$('#success').html('');
});
```

This is the PHP code which I am using with the html and js to send the data in email

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
empty($_POST['email'])     ||
empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
empty($_POST['arrival'])   ||
empty($_POST['departure'])   ||
//empty($_POST['people'])   ||
//empty($_POST['roomtype'])   ||
empty($_POST['message'])   ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
}
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$emailadd = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$arrival = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['arrival']));
$departure = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['departure']));
$people = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['people']));
$roomtype = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['roomtype']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'lamers1963@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Booking Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $emailadd\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nArrival: $arrival\n\nDeparture: $departure\n\nPeople: $people\n\nRoomtype: $roomtype\n\nMessage: $message";
$headers = "From: noreply\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Comment: Not a jquery fan, but is `$("input#people").val();` correct when it's a `select`, not an `input`?

Comment: Pleassse indent your code. This is very hard to read.

Comment: @Michel You are correct, it is not. Either `$("#people").val();` or `$("select#people").val();` should work

Comment: On a sidenote: `firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');` is destined to fail some time, as some people have spaces in their last name (like _Werner Von Braun_, whose first name is _Werner_, not _Werner Von_. Better ask for first and last name seperately.

Answer (score 0):

To get value of dropdown you have to use 'select' instead of 'input' in javascript.

Change these two variable's value in javascript code in `submitSuccess` :

```
var people = $("select#people").val();
var roomtype = $("select#roomtype").val();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. It actually addressed my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Add `method=post`, see docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

```
<form method="post">
...
</form>
```

Comment: They are sending through AJAX. The form method isn't used. `$.ajax({
url: "././mail/bookmail/mail/book.php",
type: "POST",`. Also, if this were the issue it wouldn't just be the `people` value that were missing, all would be.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).